# Don't get the result in Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

Just started with development in Java ADT. I created a textfield and a button in Activity_Main.xml. Then When I run the MainActivity.java the emulator starts but it's always a black background + some buttons in the right frame. I should see a textfield and a button instead of a black background.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

I've checked some guides of this problem but without result. I'm considering installing Eclipse instead. One theory is that I'm using blanc space in my path to SDK. I know this can cause issues with the Emulator.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the speed of the computer, but you have to wait for the actual android device to boot up for a long time. It will show a black screen for a while. Mine takes 5 min. So try waiting for 5 min and get back to us.

Answer (score 0):

If it's too slow for you, you can try speeding it up by using add-on from Intel. Follow this link for instruction http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture. Note: Can only be used with Intel architecture.